# "Резиновое" отображение элементов

Tags: html, css

Приветствую.

Не знаю, правильно ли я назвал этот метод "резиновым", но сейчас объясню подробнее.

Допустим, у меню менюшка отображается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у другого пользователя, так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно понял, это зависит от ширины экрана.

Как мне сделать ширину "фиксированной"? В .css много где используется margin auto, похоже это и нужно исправлять. Только вот как мне узнать какой именно .css исправлять и **у какого именно элемента** (в данном случае, например)?

```html
<?php echo $loginheader ?>
<div class="center-content">
 <form action="#" id="loginForm" class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-11 center-margin" method="post">
  <h3 class="text-center pad25B font-gray font-size-23">Control Panel<br><span class="opacity-80">Панель управления серверами</span></h3>
  <div id="login-form" class="content-box">
   <div class="content-box-wrapper pad20A">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon addon-inside bg-white font-primary">
      <i class="glyph-icon icon-linecons-mail"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <span class="input-group-addon addon-inside bg-white font-primary">
      <i class="glyph-icon icon-linecons-key"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="button-pane">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Войти</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="redirect('/account/register')">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onClick="redirect('/account/restore')">Восстановить пароль</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="redirect('/account/activation')">Активировать аккаунт</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
<script>
 $('#loginForm').ajaxForm({ 
  url: '/account/login/ajax',
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   data = $.parseJSON(data);
   switch(data.status) {
    case 'error':
     //showError(data.error);
     $.jGrowl(data.error, { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-red" });
     $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
     break;
    case 'success':
     //showSuccess(data.success);
     $.jGrowl(data.success, { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-green" });
     setTimeout("redirect('/')", 1500);
     break;
   }
  },
  beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
   $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
  }
 });
</script>
<?php echo $loginfooter ?>
```

```html
.center-vertical .center-content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ui-dialog-buttonpane, body .button-pane {
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
border-width: 1px 0 0;
border-style: solid;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
.post-box textarea{font-size:18px;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;min-height:80px;padding:15px;border:0}.post-box .button-pane .glyph-icon{font-size:13px}.post-box .button-pane .hover-white:hover{background:#fff}.post-box .button-pane{text-align:left}.post-box .button-pane .btn-post{font-size:13px;font-weight:700;text-transform:uppercase}.profile-box.content-box .content-box-header{line-height:1.6em;height:auto;padding:15px!important}.profile-box .content-box-header img{float:left;margin:0 15px 0 0}.profile-box .content-box-header .user-details{font-size:16px;position:relative;overflow:hidden;padding-top:5px}.profile-box .content-box-header .user-details span{font-size:13px;display:block;opacity:.8;text-transform:none;-moz-opacity:.8;filter:alpha(opacity:80)}.profile-box-alt .content-box-header{text-align:center}.profile-box .pie-wrapper{padding:20px;text-align:center}.profile-box .pie-wrapper canvas{display:block;margin:0 auto}.profile-box div.list-group{margin-bottom:0!important;border:0}.profile-box div.list-group a.list-group-item{border-right:0;border-left:0}.profile-box div.list-group a.list-group-item.active{margin-right:-1px;margin-left:-1px}.profile-box div.list-group a.list-group-item:last-child{border-bottom:0;border-radius:0}.profile-box div.list-group a.list-group-item:first-child{border-top:0;border-radius:0}.profile-box .list-group.list-group-separator.row{padding:10px}.profile-box .list-group.list-group-separator a.list-group-item:after{right:-10px}.profile-box ul.list-group{margin:10px 0}.profile-box .nav>li>a{padding:0}.profile-box .nav{margin-bottom:0!important}.profile-box .nav.nav-justified{margin:0!important}
```

```html
.dashboard-box{text-align:center}.dashboard-box .content-wrapper{overflow:hidden;margin:0 15px 15px;padding:15px 0 0}.dashboard-box canvas{display:block!important;margin:0 auto}.dashboard-box .header{font-size:14px;line-height:1.3em;padding:0 0 15px;text-align:right;display:block}.dashboard-box .header .btn{display:inline-block}.dashboard-box .header>.glyph-icon{display:block;float:left;width:20px}.dashboard-box .header>span{font-size:12px;font-weight:700;display:block;opacity:.8;-moz-opacity:.8;filter:alpha(opacity:80)}.dashboard-box .button-pane{border-top:0;color:#fff;background:rgba(0,0,0,.08)}.bg-white.dashboard-box .button-pane{border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1px}.dashboard-box .heading{font-size:15px;font-weight:700;float:left}.dashboard-box .center-div{margin:5px auto -15px}.dashboard-heading{font-size:14px;padding:0 0 10px}.dashboard-heading span{font-size:12px;display:block}body .button-pane.button-pane-alt{background:0 0!important}.dashboard-panel .chosen-container-single .chosen-single span{padding-right:40px}.dashboard-panel .chosen-container{margin-top:-3px;text-align:left}a.dashboard-box,a.dashboard-box>span{display:block}a.dashboard-box .button-pane{text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase}a.dashboard-box .button-pane .heading{font-weight:400}.dashboard-box-chart .bs-label{position:absolute;right:15px;top:15px}.dashboard-box-chart .header{text-align:left;font-size:28px;font-weight:300;letter-spacing:1px;line-height:1}.dashboard-box-chart .header span{text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:0;padding:10px 0 0;line-height:1.8em;text-align:center;opacity:.8;-moz-opacity:.8;filter:alpha(opacity:80)}.dashboard-box-chart .header span b{opacity:.65;-moz-opacity:.65;filter:alpha(opacity:65)}.dashboard-box-chart .list-grade{opacity:.5;-moz-opacity:.5;filter:alpha(opacity:50);margin-top:25px}.dashboard-box-chart .button-pane{padding:10px 10px 10px 15px}.dashboard-box-chart .button-pane .btn .glyph-icon{min-width:11px;display:block}.dashboard-box-chart .button-pane .size-md{font-size:16px}
```

Comment: Для более правильного и точного ответа не помешает html и css сего окошка

Comment: Код вашей формы подкрепите

Comment: @andreymal, html код добавил, но вот какой .css не знаю.

Comment: @Максим, а вы не думаете, что при установке фиксированной ширины на узких экранах пользователи смогут не увидеть все кнопки под полем пароля?

Comment: @Максим не, без css фигово

Comment: @Максим Осмелюсь предположить, что за размер Вашего окна отвечает класс "center-content". Приложите код этого класса к Вашему вопросу. И также CSS класса button-pane.

Comment: @Legionary, приложил.
Visman, я не собираюсь на миллионы увеличивать. Или вы можете предложить другой вариант?

Comment: @Максим с помощью этого css нельзя получить форму такую же, как на скриншоте, так что он неполный и на вопрос всё ещё нельзя точно ответить (можно неточно, но лично я не хочу)

Comment: @andreymal, вот я прикрепил два .css где используется .button-pane, но вид там ужасный (всё в одну строку).

Comment: @Максим неа, получить картинку как на скриншоте всё ещё не получается

Answer (score 2):

Самым простым решением данной проблемы могу предложить дописать  `width: 500px;` в CSS, а именно:

```
.ui-dialog-buttonpane, body .button-pane {
width: 500px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
border-width: 1px 0 0;
border-style: solid;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: У меня последняя кнопка съехала вниз.

Comment: @Максим попробуйте"поиграться" с width, чуть больше прикрутите, 505, 510 - в итоге должно вытянуться прямой объект. 
(Как вариант тестирования могу предложить, открыть исходный код страницы, а конкретно элемента этого, и, что говорится, в live режиме "подбирать" подходящий Вам размер width.)

Comment: сразу же так и попробовал. В итоге на 700 кнопка вернулась наверх, но "полоска" где кнопки - съехала немного в право.

Answer (score 2):

А `width` в процентах указывать? Не помогло? В стиле:

```
element {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 20px
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: Учитывали отступ после кнопки при указании `width`?

Comment: И до кнопки тоже нужно учитывать, забыл указать

Comment: Похоже, там дело не в css, а в скриптах. Если кому интересно, посмотрите пожалуйста: astera-project.ru

Comment: Попробуй сделать форму шире и обьеденить кнопки в `.row`, с помощью `.col-xs-1` или `col-xs-2` и подобного задавай ширину, а у кнопок сделай `width: 100%`. Хотя, я думаю и это не поможет, так как минимальная ширина кнопки равна ширине текста, а тут ничего не поделать. Попробуй избавиться от кнопки "восстановить пароль" путем добавления ссылки под форму после неправильного ввода пароля. Кнопка "активировать аккаунт" тоже неуместна, ее можно в профиль переместить.

Comment: если бы проблема была только в этой менюшке, я бы даже не заикался. Дело в том, что вся панель написана таким образом.